# Objective-C, upload file to s3

Tags: objective-c, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a problem when following the tutorial http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html#get-the-sdk to upload file from my iOS app to S3.

I download the AWS-SDK and import all the frameworks I need to my project, but when I compile it, it seems in the file `AWSSTSService.h`, it searches for a header file called `AWSCoreAWSCore.h`.

It does the import like:

```
import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
import AWSCoreAWSCore.h         -----> cannot find it
import "AWSSTSModel.h"
```

I use the following frameworks:

AWSCore.framework

AWSS3.framework

AWSCognito.framework

This is AWS framework so I don't want to change its code, but I cannot find such header file in entire AWS-SDK folder.

Comment: i think the import is #import <AWSCore/AWSCore.h>

Comment: or #import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>       #import <FRAMEWORKNAME/SERVICENAME.h>